# List Selector Widget Color in Einstein

Tags: einstein-analytics, einstein

Brand new to Einstein Analytics.  Is there a way to change the text color for a List widget? Definitely don't see one in the regular Dashboard design, but I can't seem to find a way to do it in JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Looked into the documentation and you can take a glance [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.bi_dev_guide_json.meta/bi_dev_guide_json/bi_dbjson_widgets_parameters_properties.htm) . Looks like there is no property to set the Text Color for list selector type yet.